# jQuery - Refresh contents of FileUploader

Tags: jquery, refresh, file-upload

I am working on a web page which has a file uploader. After I click the button 'Discard changes', I want the contents of the file uploader to be purged.  I was thinking to do this by refreshing the fileuploader using jQuery.

How can this be done in jQuery please?  Thanks :)

**Edit**

The file uploader I am using makes use of a jQuery library so that it can upload several photos at once.  As a result, changing its value to "" does not work in this case.

That's why I'd like to reload it all together using jQuery.

This is the plugin I am using:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317

Comment: This is the plugin I am using: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317

Comment: Unfortunately that plugin is not flexible at all. Just emptying out the div contents doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks Interstellar_Coder :)  I will try to find a better plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the File input an id or a class, let's say this id is "img" and then use

```
$('input#img').val("");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should have mentioned in my question that I am using a jQuery plugin so that the FileUploader can upload several images at once.

Comment: That's why I was thinking to refresh the fileuploader all together.

Comment: Ok, the thing is, javascript can only do as much as change the value displayed in the uploader, it is not authorized to delete the file mounted in the uploader since javascript cannot handle files, you could put the form in a separate file and use jQuery's load() function like this: 
$('div#foo').load('link/to/file/containing/form.php');